# Is it wise to create a unlocked package around a single open source library or to have multiple open source libraries in a sort of open source pkg?

Tags: package, unlocked-package

We are breaking up our monolith unlocked package which has the following libraries and custom code:

```
FFLIB
Force-DI
ApexMocks
Apex Enterprise Patterns
3rd party integrations
Some Inhouse selectors/frameworks that are built on top of FFLIB
```

In breaking up the package to smaller packages, I was thinking of putting 3rd party open source libraries in their own package.

For example I could put FFLIB in it's own package that requires the ApexMocks package.

OR Should I bundle them all under a open source package of sorts and we update that only when we are comfortable with the version.

Does have anyone have any pro or cons with either of these approaches?

I guess what is a good balance of modularity versus practicality.

Comment: I have independently and successfully updated apexmocks asynchronously from updating fflib as I wanted only feats from apexmocks without going through the more extensive validation of latest fflib feats -- so I'd be OK w/ fflib having a dependency on a separate package apexmocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Larger packages take more time to install than smaller packages. In addition, there is a delay in between installation of multiple packages, which can eventually overtake the amount of time it takes to install a large package.

When you create a package version, a virtual org is spun up, all of the dependencies are installed, and then the metadata to become a version is validated and packaged. This happens every time you create a full unlocked package version. You can disable validation and/or use an Org Dependent package approach, but these packages are of relatively limited functionality. At some point, if you want a package that can be migrated to a production org, it needs to be validated, and this is what will take up quite a bit of time.

This creates a balancing act in package design. If you have a ton of small packages that every other package will depend on, you'll spend more time on version creation than having a single large package. On the other hand, if most of your packages will only depend on a few small packages, you can drastically improve packaging times by breaking up your code into small packages.

There is no "one right answer" to your situation. You might want to analyze/document which packages depend on which open-source libraries, and then determine which would be approximately more efficient. You might decide that most packages need the entire suite of code you're using, and a monolith package will offer you the most convenience. Or, you might find that most of your packages will only need one or two packages, and you can save a significant amount of time on version creation. Or, you might even figure out that most of your packages need most of the libraries, but maybe you can split some of the less-commonly used stuff into a separate package.

So, in summary, more packages can reduce package version creation times, but fewer packages can reduce the maintenance associated with having a lot of dependencies (e.g. fewer installs to do on a regular basis). It really depends on what your priorities are. And, keep in mind, that either decision will largely not influence the amount of time it takes to install the packages you create that depend on those packages, so having a simple monolith package might offer you the most convenience at the cost of version creation times.

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox. I have learnt a lot from you. Thank you again